# iOS GCD Thread Processing - View Controller Dismissed

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, background-process

Consider the following code in a ViewController which runs when the user clicks a button:

```
var myBlock = {
    [weak self] in
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        // Some heavy lifting code with final UI Feedback
        let success = true
        if(success) {
            if let strongSelf = self {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    // Tell user it was successful
                    strongSelf.label1.text = "SUCCESS!"
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the area where the heavy lifting occurs, lets say there is a process that takes about 5-10 seconds. If during that period the user dismisses the ViewController in which this code resides, does the background thread continue to run? If so, when the success block runs and attempts to access the UI element on the UI thread, what happens?

Ultimately, I am trying to understand the best practice for queueing a process in the background that updates the UI when possible. Also, if the user presses the home button, this process MUST continue in the background to completion. I have read that you can add: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler()` Is that meant to operate inside a thread as seen above?

I'm sure this is a bit of a noob question, but I could really use some best practice guidance here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference to self inside a block a strong reference is stored in order to keep the reference until it is executed. The best practice is to create a weak self version to avoid retain cycles. You can achieve this creating the weak version outside the block like so in Objective C:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

And in Swift:

```
var myBlock = {
[weak self] in
//some work with self
}
```

and access weakSelf instead of self in the block.

You can learn a little bit more in the next [link](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/objective-c-blocks-caveat/).

The background thread will continue to run, you can implement NSOperations if you need to be a cancelable task. If you can unwrap the optional inside the block you can update the UI.

About beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, it is used to mark the beginning of a long task you are about to start and get an extra time to complete it (and notify when it is done) in case the App is backgrounded, but if it can't be performed in that time the app will be terminated. You can use it if you needed, but it will not ensure to have the time to done your task.

Comment: So lets say it is a weak reference created through an IBOutlet using the storyboard. The property would be declared: @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

if I access that self.label1?.text = "SUCCESS" it will be ok?

Comment: Also, I am assuming you are saying that the thread will continue even though the ViewController was dismissed?

Comment: The thread will continue executing (but you'll avoid memory leak), if you have some heavy process you can implement NSOperation cancelable, in this way it can avoid execute extra process. If you want to learn more about NSOperations there is a video in WWDC 2012 that explains it very well, the name of the video is "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS".

Comment: Ok. So with the weak reference, would I need to check self for nil  first? I am guessing self get de-initialized or nilled out when the ViewController disposes. Is this correct?

Comment: I will depend, in case you send a message to nil, the message will be ignored. But maybe you need to execute the whole block or nothing, so in that case you can create a strong version of weakSelf inside the block. Maybe this [post](https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/) helps.

Comment: Interesting. In my case, if the user has lost interest and dismissed the ViewController, I would not want to bother attempting to update the UI. So with a weak reference, I can check for nil. If weakSelf is nil, I can just return from the block without attempting to update the UI. Is this correct?

Comment: Updated my question based on your feedback. Can you take a look and see if I have understood? Also, do you have a response for my question regarding the background processing using UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler()